# chrome.exe --version does not print version on Windows

Tags: google-chrome

On Linux and OS X, calling the chrome executable with `--version` simply prints the version and exits with 0.

On windows however, calling

```
chrome.exe --version
```

Does not print the version and actually launches the browser.

Any idea what's going on here, does the windows version of chrome not support the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is an already recognized issue, but still hasn't been fixed (since October 2012, when it was reported), as you can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158372)

> --version works fine in Mac OS X, just not Windows.

A user also points out that a possible workaround is to run the following command:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v DisplayVersion
```

But I honestly haven't been able to succesfully run it (the registry key doesn't seem to be there).

Anyways, you might be interested in taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203947/windows-registry-location-for-google-chrome-version) for other alternatives (apart from `chrome://version`).